# Link received in an email launches in the new tab of already running browser instead of default OS browser

Tags: email, browser, url

Suppose my default OS browser is Chrome.
I am accessing gmail in a different browser (Mozilla or IE).
There is a web link in one of the received mails.
When I click on that link, the link opens up in another tab of the already running instance of browser.

To summarize, it ignores the default OS browser settings.

Even if you replace gmail with Outlook and change the browser, the same behavior occurs (The web link always launches in new tab of that browser which is already running.

Can this behavior be explained?

To be frank, I am ok with this behavior but need some technical explanation so that I can explain it to an irate customer.

Comment: First of all.. Real support for IE11 ended with Windows 7.  I know some businesses are using specific plugins for it but that browser is garbage.  A browser can do whatever it wants to handle a media type (mime).   How can your customer somehow blame you for the behavior of a program you didn't even write?

Comment: I think IE 11 only has security updates in W10, but it doesnt have support since W7, for me it's an outdated navigator and the client should acknowledge that in first place.

Comment: Hi Senor, it's not about a particular browser such as IE11.
You can take any 2 browsers (latest supported ones), then set one of them as a default browser and open your email (gmail, outlook, etc) in the other browser.
The same phenomenon would be reproduced and the default OS browser would not be used to open that link.
The email client (web interface) which I support also shows same behavior as expected. 
I understand that this behavior is controlled by browser. But what makes it ignore default OS browser settings?

Comment: *I understand that this behavior is controlled by browser. But what makes it ignore default OS browser settings?*.. you answered your question yourself.. or I guess you could say "the programmer"?  As long as the "browser wars" exist.. (and they still do), this behavior will continue.

Comment: Thanks Senor!!
Is there any Google or Microsoft support document explaining about the same.
I searched for it frantically over the net, but could not find anything which would help me.
It would be of great help if such a document is available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly simplifying, but here's the basics:

Any web content at its basis is delivered over a series of technologies known as "http" or "https" which is short for "(secure) hyper-text transfer protocol" (the 's 'in https standing for 'secure')
The basic behaviour of https is: **if you click on something in order to see new content, you instruct your browser to follow a hyper-link** (aka "a link"). That's why it is called "hyper-text", because it contains not only text but also "hyper-links" !

**Your gmail inbox,** at its basis is nothing but **a list of hyper-links,** or simply links, pointing to your various emails.  The labels on the left such as "inbox" or "thrash" are links. Even the settings-gear is a (sophisticated) link ! They may LOOK different, but they WORK in the same basic way!

Now, **for how http is conceived at its basis,** your browser has **no possibility to know** if that link you are clicking belongs to **a functionality** of gmail, such as "open the next email", or if it is **a link** within the body of your email: for your browser, simply there is **no difference** between the two! The fact that the external link opens in a new browser tab, is coded into the way the gmail (or outlook) website works, it is not decided by the browser (but as a user you can right-click a link and to some extent decide where within the browser that link should open).

So what your client is asking for would **totally break the basic behaviour of any browser.**
It would also break basic security measures built in your operating system: a link from within a browser may not open another piece of software, except with the explicit consent of the user.  This is to avoid that malware can install on your computer (beware of any browser plugins which break that principle!)

(It probably could be possible to write a custom browser which does what your client asks, by reverse-engineering the gmail website, but at any code change by google, you would risk having random browser windows popping up on your desktop - I'm simplifying a bit for the sake of metaphors.  Purists may excuse me)

If your client wishes **a dedicated application for reading emails,** and have links sent by email open in a different software, they should consider **installing a dedicated email client** such as Thunderbird (which is freeware). The behaviour of such software is not based on http, and any link you click within them will be passed to the operating system to open in the browser of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think if a browser is already running, it should obviously  open the link in a new tab of the same browser instead of checking for the compatible app to open the link and then referring the OS browser preference.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer wishes browsing and email in separate windows, then you can add Gmail as a Chrome ["app"](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en) and pin to task bar - similar to using Thunderbird.
But i would recommend Thunderbird, as it can [open different emails in different tabs](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/features/).

Drawback of using 2 windows of the same browser: the main Chrome window should always be started first, otherwise existing tabs may be lost when opening a link in an eMail. Workaround: use [SessionBuddy](https://sessionbuddy.com/) to restore tabs when lost, it can be configured to show the number of open tabs.

Easiest solution with everything in one window: use Gmail as a Firefox [pinned tab](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open).

[image: 2 Chrome windows]